# JavaFX StringBindings

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

---

I am currently learning **JavaFX** and I have some trouble with **String Bindings**. I have the following **three** questions:

1. It is my goal to update the View (`labelTime` and `labelMoneyEarned`) whenever the values in the model (`model.runningWorkpackage.durationFormated` and `model.MoneyEarnedSum`) are updated. I try to achieve this with Bindings like this: `labelTime.textProperty().bind(model.runningWorkpackage.durationFormated);` and `labelMoneyEarnedSum.textProperty().bind((Bindings.format("%.2f Euro", model.moneyEarnedSum)));` But the label do **not** update. What did I understand wrong?
2. I am getting **NullPointerExceptions** if I do not initialise the Properties used for my Bindings while declaring them with: `private IntegerProperty duration =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "duration", 0);` and `public Workpackage runningWorkpackage = new Workpackage();` How can I initialise them in the constructor. Is that the proper place?
3. Do I understand it right that:

   ```
   public StringBinding durationFormated = new StringBinding()
   {
       {
           super.bind(duration);
       }

       @Override
       protected String computeValue()
       {
           return Util.formatTime(duration.intValue());
       }
   };
   ```

   and

   ```
   public StringBinding durationFormated Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
               return Util.formatTime(duration.intValue());
    }, duration);
   ```

will create the same Bindings?

Thanks for your help! :)

---

## Relevant Code:

### Controller

```
public void init(Model model)
{
    // Model
    this.model = model;
    ...
    ...
    labelTime.textProperty().bind(model.runningWorkpackage.durationFormated);
    labelMoneyEarnedSum.textProperty().bind((Bindings.format("%.2f Euro", model.moneyEarnedSum)));

}
```

### Model

```
public class Model
{
    public ObservableList<Workpackage> workpackages =     FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public Workpackage runningWorkpackage = new Workpackage();

    public Model()
    {
        workpackages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public DoubleBinding moneyEarnedSum = new DoubleBinding()
    {
        {
            super.bind(workpackages);
        }

        @Override
        protected double computeValue()
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (Workpackage wp : workpackages)
            {
                sum += wp.getMoneyEarned();
            }
            return sum;
        }
    };
}
```

### Workpackage

```
public class Workpackage
{
    private IntegerProperty duration =  new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "duration", 0);
    private DoubleProperty moneyEarned;

    // Start Workpackage
    public Workpackage()
    {
        duration = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "duration", 0);

        moneyEarned = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "moneyEarned", 0);
        moneyEarned.bind(duration.multiply(Util.moneyPerSecond));
    }

    public StringBinding durationFormated = new StringBinding()
    {
        {
            super.bind(duration);
        }

        @Override
        protected String computeValue()
        {
            return Util.formatTime(duration.intValue());
        }
    };


    //      public StringBinding durationFormated = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    //              return Util.formatTime(duration.intValue());
    //          }, duration);


    // Duration
    public final int getDuration()
    {
        return duration.get();
    }

    public final void setDuration(int duration)
    {
        this.duration.set(duration);
    }

    public IntegerProperty durationProperty()
    {
        return duration;
    }


    // MoneyEarned
    public final double getMoneyEarned()
    {
        return moneyEarned.get();
    }

    public final void setMoneyEarned(double moneyEarned)
    {
        this.moneyEarned.set(moneyEarned);
    }

    public DoubleProperty moneyEarnedProperty()
    {
        return moneyEarned;
    }
}
```

### Thread

```
public class TimerThread extends Thread
{
    Model model;

    public TimerThread(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(Util.running)
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e){}

            model.runningWorkpackage.setDuration(model.runningWorkpackage.getDuration() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i understand correctly you want to display some datas from your model and if the model is updated, the labels also to be updated? Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I did a little experimentation and I think I found the solution.
You have an own `TimerThread` class but you can use the java build in `java.util.Timer`. So my classes look like this:

Here is the **model**:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Model {

    private StringProperty string;

    public Model(String string) {
        this.string = new SimpleStringProperty(string);
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string.get();
    }

    public StringProperty stringProperty() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Here is the **Controller**:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestController implements Initializable {

    private static final int DELAY = 0;
    private static final int PERIOD = 1000;

    @FXML
    private Label myLabel;

    private Model model;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        model = new Model("");
        myLabel.textProperty().bind(model.stringProperty());
        doTheTask();
    }

    private void doTheTask() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(() -> model.stringProperty().set(LocalTime.now().toString()));
            }
        }, DELAY, PERIOD);
    }
}
```

So this litte example displays the time that is updated in every second.

I think this example can help you to solve your problem.
If you are using threads, timers in javafx you should use `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: I see you are using integers to hold the value of the duration, but you can convert that `Integer` to `String` easily for example in the constructor, and its much easier to work with `String` while you want to display its value.